# Rest template post call returning 500 error

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am trying to call a rest endpoint by passing an object and get the response. It is working in postman. Here is my url: https://test.ap.com/rest/user/create

body:{ "gender":"MALE", "weight":965.0, "height":40.0, "name":"testuser" }

and the response is

{ "id":"1234", "token":"1234%" }

Here is my code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/createUser", method = { RequestMethod.POST})
    public  createUserInfo() throws Exception
    {
       UserData userData = new UserData();
       userData.setGender("MALE");
       userData.setWeight(965.0);
       userData.setHeight(40.0);
        userData.setName("test1");

        String url="https://test.ap.com/rest/user/create";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(userData, headers);

        ResponseEntity<Object[]> response= restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, Object[].class);


    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:407)
    at
```

I tried to change the headers and  created an object for response type but nothing worked for me. what else I should add to fix this?

Comment: Why do you try to receive Array of Objects via RestTemplate while you are obviously getting a single Object as a response in Postman?

Comment: I tried with this statement as well  User response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, User.class); this one also getting 500 error. where user class has two fields id and token

Comment: The code looks valid. Maybe try to add `headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);` ?

Comment: I added this statement as well but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
String url="https://test.ap.com/rest/user/create";
```

should be

```
String url="https://test.ap.com/rest/user/create/";
```

for some reason that last slash is really important